# JMeter share Regular Expression array variables between Thread Groups

Tags: multithreading, jmeter

In Thread Group #1 I have a Regular Expression with Match Number set to -1 and I want to use the complete variable in Thread Group #2.

I am currently able to share normal variables using props.put but I am not able to share the complete array to then obtain the values using __V function on Thread Group #2.

Is this feasible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) (make sure it goes **after** Regular Expression Extractor) and use the following code:

```
vars.entrySet().each { var ->
    if (var.getKey().startsWith('foo')) {
        props.put(var.getKey(), var.getValue())
    }
}
```

In another Thread Group you can convert properties into variables using the same approach:

```
props.entrySet().each {prop ->
   if (prop.getKey().startsWith('foo')){
        vars.put(prop.getKey(),prop.getValue())
   }
}
```

Just replace `foo` with your variable reference name and that would be it.

You can find information regarding Groovy scripting in JMeter in [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) guide if needed.